# try-with-resources where to wrap stream with InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, java-7

I may be overthinking this, but I just wrote the code:

```
try (InputStream in = ModelCodeGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/model.java.txt"))
{
    modelTemplate = new SimpleTemplate(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(in, "ascii")));
}
```

Which means the InputStreamReader is never closed (but in this case we know its close method just closes the underlying InputStream.)

One could write it as:

```
try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(...))
```

But this seems worse. If InputStreamReader throws for some reason, the InputStream won't ever be closed, right? This is a common problem in C++ with constructors that call other constructors. Exceptions can cause memory/resource leaks.

Is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Which means the InputStreamReader is never closed

Eh? In your code it is... And it will certainly handle the .close() of your resource stream as well. See below for more details...

[As @SotiriosDelimanolis mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28074428/1093528) however you can declare more than one resource in the "resource block" of a try-with-resources statement.

You have another problem here: `.getResourceAsStream()` can return null; you may therefore have an NPE.

I'd do this if I were you:

```
final URL url = ModelCodeGenerator.class.getClassLoader()
    .getResource("/model.java.txt");

if (url == null)
    throw new IOException("resource not found");

try (
    final InputStream in = url.openStream();
    final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, someCharsetOrDecoder);
) {
    // manipulate resources
}
```

There is a **very important point to consider** however...

`Closeable` does extend `AutoCloseable`, yes; in fact it only differs, "signature wise", by the exception thrown (`IOException` vs `Exception`). But there is a fundamental difference in *behavior*.

From the javadoc of `AutoCloseable`'s `.close()` (emphasis mine):

> **Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this close method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike Closeable.close which is required to have no effect if called more than once**. However, implementers of this interface are strongly encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.

And indeed, the javadoc of `Closeable` is clear about this:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it. If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

You have two very important points:

- by contract, a `Closeable` also takes care of all resources associated with it; so, if you close a `BufferedReader` which wraps a `Reader` which wraps an `InputStream`, all three are closed;
- should you call `.close()` more than once, there is no further side effect.

This also means, of course, that you can choose the paranoid option and keep a reference to *all* `Closeable` resources and close them all; beware however if you have `AutoCloseable` resources into the mix which are not `Closeable`!

Comment: I guess closing both is the safe way. It's overkill here, and we know that, but depending on implementation details for safety is a bad practice. Good catch with the NPE by the way.

Comment: Updated answer for completeness!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer! When checking for the NPE, the code is obvious, you only need the InputStreamReader in the try-with-resources, because when that auto-closes it will close the underlying stream, as you rightly point out.

Comment: However, the behavior that prompted this question was the case where you do try(reader = new InputStreamReader(getResourceAsStream("..."))). In that case, if there is an exception during construction of InputStreamReader, then I imagine reader.close() is never called (reader doesn't exist yet) BUT the stream was opened, has no named reference, and will never be closed, possible finalizers aside. That seems to me to be an easy error to make and a hard one to catch. C++ suffers from this more commonly.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right; only resources "safely declared" in a try-with-resources block will be safely closed, if you "chain" them then this is not the case.

Comment: What surprised me is the official docs themselves give: `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)))` which violates that principle.

Comment: Well, I suppose the official resources assume a sane behavior of their own classes ;) But you're right, in this respect, the documentation is certainly lacking. Ultimately, I do agree with you that each resource should be declared separately; when I was still working with Java 6, I always used Guava's `Closer` to properly "isolate" the resources as well...

Answer (score 6):

> But this seems worse. If `InputStreamReader` throws for some reason, the
>   `InputStream` won't ever be closed, right?

That's right (although unlikely, the `InputStreamReader` constructor doesn't really do much).

The [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) lets you declare as many resources as you'd like. Declare one for the wrapped resource, and another for the `InputStreamReader`.

```
try (InputStream in = ModelCodeGenerator.class
             .getClassLoader()
             .getResourceAsStream("/model.java.txt");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in)) {...}
```

Note that `getResourceAsStream` can potentially return `null`, which would cause the `InputStreamReader` constructor to throw a `NullPointerException`. If you want to deal with that differently, adapt how you retrieve the resource that's meant to be wrapped.

The tutorial linked above presents this example

```
try (
    java.util.zip.ZipFile zf =
         new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
    java.io.BufferedWriter writer = 
        java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
) {
```

with the explanation

> In this example, the try-with-resources statement contains two
>   declarations that are separated by a semicolon: `ZipFile` and
>   `BufferedWriter`. When the block of code that directly follows it
>   terminates, either normally or because of an exception, the close
>   methods of the `BufferedWriter` and `ZipFile` objects are automatically
>   called in this order. Note that the close methods of resources are
>   called in the opposite order of their creation.